# Get the pid if 2 tomcat(s) is running

Tags: linux, tomcat, grep, ps, pid

I have 2 tomcat's running, how do I get the pid if both have similar names?

```
ps -ef | grep java
root     12952     1  0 10:01 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid-ws/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid-ws/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid-ws/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid-ws -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid-ws -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid-ws/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     12995     1  0 10:02 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid/bin/bootstrap.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/realbid/tomcat-realbid/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     13317 12252  0 10:12 pts/0    00:00:00 grep java
```

If I use basic grep I get both the pid(s)

```
echo `ps aux | grep  'tomcat-realbid' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
12952 12995
```

Is there a way to get only the pid of `tomcat-realbid`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inverse grep so perhaps:

```
ps aux | grep 'tomcat-realbid' | grep -v 'tomcat-realbid-ws'
```

This would basically filter for the processes with tomcat-realbid and then filter again removing any that have tomcat-realbid-ws, you are already using an inverse grep to remove the original grep. The end result may look like this:

```
echo ps aux | grep  'tomcat-realbid' | grep -v 'tomcat-realbid-ws' | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: yeah , forgot about the v option , it works now , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try :

```
pgrep tomcat-realbid
```

Comment: pgrep does not return any output                       [root@kibana bin]# echo `ps aux | pgrep  tomcat-realbid | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ps auxwww | grep "/tomcat-realbid/"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter:

```
pgrep 'tomcat-realbid[^(-ws)]*$'
```

Searches for `tomcat-realbid` without the ending `-ws` and prints the pid.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `awk` can do what `grep` does, so you can join all the commands in just one:

```
ps -ef | awk '/java/ && /tomcat-realbid / {print $2}'
```

This gets all those lines containing both `java` and `tomcat-realbid` (note the space at the end, just to get the one you wanted). For those matchines lines, it prints its 2nd field.